# Magento 2 Cookie not able to clear from JS

Tags: magento2, javascript, cookie

I am unable to clear the cookie on my Magento site.

I am setting the cookie as below which is done successfully

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;


$publicCookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
$publicCookieMetadata->setPath('/');
$publicCookieMetadata->setHttpOnly(false);
$publicCookieMetadata->setSameSite('Strict');
$this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
    self::COOKIE_NAME,
    1,
    $publicCookieMetadata
);
```

After that, I am reading the cookie in my JS file and then trying to clear it as below:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Abc_Gtm/js/dataLayerPush',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($, ui, dlp) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('gtm.loginSuccess', {
        _create: function () {
            var gtmLogin = $.mage.cookies.get('gtmLoginEventTrigger');
            if(gtmLogin === "1") {
                dlp('event_crm_action','event_profile_login_complete','');
                $.mage.cookies.clear('gtmLoginEventTrigger');
            }
            console.log($.mage.cookies.get('gtmLoginEventTrigger'));
        }
    });
    return $.gtm.loginSuccess;
});
```

The function of clear cookies is executed successfully but it doesn't clear the cookie. I also tried setting another value using `mage.cookies.set()` However, that too isn't working.

Checked disabling cache and all other solution. Can anyone suggest a better way out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the cookies you are trying to modify aren't HttpOnly. Such cookies are sent in the HTTP headers only and aren't accessible directly by JavaScript.

Maybe this will be helpful to you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387338/what-is-a-host-only-cookie/28320172#28320172

You may try to pass `domain` (`->setDomain()`) as `.domain.com` and after you can remove those cookie